# How to take as Input a list of arrays in Keras API

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Well, i'm new to Machine Learning, and so with Keras. I'm trying to create a model from which can be passed as Input a list of arrays of arrays (a list of 6400 arrays within 2 arrays).
This is my code's problem:

```
XFIT = np.array([x_train, XX_train])
YFIT = np.array([y_train, yy_train])
Inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(6400, 2))
hidden1 = keras.layers.Dense(units=100, activation="sigmoid")(Inputs)
hidden2 = keras.layers.Dense(units=100, activation='relu')(hidden1)
predictions = keras.layers.Dense(units=3, activation='softmax')(hidden2)

model = keras.Model(inputs=Inputs, outputs=predictions)
```

There's no error; however, the Input layer (Inputs) forces me to pass a (6400, 2) shape, as each array (x_train and XX_train) has 6400 arrays inside. The result, with the epochs done, is this:

```
Train on 2 samples
Epoch 1/5

2/2 [==============================] - 1s 353ms/sample - loss: 1.1966 - accuracy: 0.2488
Epoch 2/5

2/2 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/sample - loss: 1.1303 - accuracy: 0.2544
Epoch 3/5

2/2 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/sample - loss: 1.0982 - accuracy: 0.3745
Epoch 4/5

2/2 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/sample - loss: 1.0854 - accuracy: 0.3745
Epoch 5/5

2/2 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/sample - loss: 1.0835 - accuracy: 0.3745

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I can't train more than twice in each epoch because of the input shape. How can I change this input?
I have triend other shapes but they got me errors.

x_train, XX_train seems like this

```
[[[0.505834 0.795461]
  [0.843175 0.975741]
  [0.22349  0.035036]
  ...
  [0.884796 0.867509]
  [0.396942 0.659936]
  [0.873194 0.05454 ]]

 [[0.95968  0.281957]
  [0.137547 0.390005]
  [0.635382 0.901555]
  ...
  [0.887062 0.486206]
  [0.49827  0.949123]
  [0.034411 0.983711]]]
```

Thank you and forgive me if i've commited any fault, first time in Keras and first time in StackOverFlow :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. The problem is with:

```
XFIT = np.array([x_train, XX_train])
YFIT = np.array([y_train, yy_train])
```

Let's see with an example:

```
import numpy as np

x_train = np.random.random((6400, 2))
y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=(6400,1))

xx_train = np.array([x_train, x_train])
yy_train = np.array([y_train, y_train])

print(xx_train.shape)
(2, 6400, 2)

print(yy_train.shape)
(2, 6400, 1)
```

In the array, we have 2 batches with 6400 samples each. This means when we call `model.fit`, it only has 2 batches to train on. Instead, what we can do:

```
xx_train = np.vstack([x_train, x_train])
yy_train = np.vstack([y_train, y_train])

print(xx_train.shape)
(12800, 2)

print(yy_train.shape)
(12800, 1)
```

Now, we have correctly joined both sample and can now train.

```
Inputs = Input(shape=(2, ))
hidden1 = Dense(units=100, activation="sigmoid")(Inputs)
hidden2 = Dense(units=100, activation='relu')(hidden1)
predictions = Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden2)

model = Model([Inputs], outputs=predictions)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(xx_train, yy_train, batch_size=10, epochs=5)

Train on 12800 samples
Epoch 1/5
12800/12800 [==============================] - 3s 216us/sample - loss: 0.6978 - acc: 0.5047
Epoch 2/5
12800/12800 [==============================] - 2s 186us/sample - loss: 0.6952 - acc: 0.5018
Epoch 3/5
12800/12800 [==============================] - 3s 196us/sample - loss: 0.6942 - acc: 0.4962
Epoch 4/5
12800/12800 [==============================] - 3s 217us/sample - loss: 0.6938 - acc: 0.4898
Epoch 5/5
12800/12800 [==============================] - 3s 217us/sample - loss: 0.6933 - acc: 0.5002
```